# Why does same static method behaves different in different controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a public static method in Invoice.cs class:

```
public static string CalculateHash(Stream image)
{
    using (var sha = SHA256.Create())
    {
        image.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var hash = sha.ComputeHash(image);
        var hashStr = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
        return hashStr;
    }

}
```

I have two controllers: HookController.cs and DataController.cs. I try to check if same hash was created for same image, But, hashes which are created by these controllers are not same for same image.

Comment: Then it stands to reason the contents of the `Stream` is not the same in both cases, despite your assertion that they're dealing with the same image. Break out the debugger and check; there's not much anyone can do to diagnose the problem from a distance.

Comment: You can just say that you had no idea. I don't want you to debug my code, or I am not incapable of debugging my code. I use same method in different places in project: a background service, two controllers and it is unusual when it works in a controller and does not in another. If you have already come across a similar problem, please do not hesitate to help. By the way, stream is same.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this way.I copied to a new memory stream.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Getting the same Hash value using the below code. Tested it on .Net Framework 4.6.1 console app.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var fileStream = new FileStream(@"D:\Mukesh\Mukesh.jpg", FileMode.Open);
            var result = CalculateHash(fileStream);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static string CalculateHash(Stream image)
        {
            using (var sha = SHA256.Create())
            {
                image.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var hash = sha.ComputeHash(image);
                var hashStr = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
                return hashStr;
            }

        }
```